# Django datetimefield time in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a `DateTimeField` in one of my models

If I display `{{ model.datetime }}` in the template, I see:

```
Aug. 13, 2013, 7:57 p.m.
```

If I display `{{ model.datetime.time }}` in the template , I see:

```
2:57 am
```

I want it to just display `7:57 p.m.` How can I get it to use the correct timezone. I have tried with `model.datetime.timetz` as well but with the same result.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
{{ model.datetime|date:"g:i a" }}
```

If you want a different format, [refer to the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: It would need to be "g:i a" to exclude the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with the default format for your local time, replacing the call to the [`time()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) with the [`time` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-time) will do the job:

```
{{ model.datetime|time }}
```

Hth,
dtk